# Finding temporary file storage in Java

Tags: java, file-io

So I'm writing a Java application that uses [Simple](http://simple.sourceforge.net/) to store data as xml file, but it is hellishly slow with big files when it stores on a network drive compared to on a local hard drive. So I'd like to store it locally before copying it over to the desired destination.

**Is there some smart way to find a temporary local file storage in Java in a system independent way?**

E.g. something that returns something such as `c:/temp` in windows, `/tmp` in linux, and likewise for other platforms (such as mac). I could use application path but the problem is that the Java application is run from the network drive as well.

Comment: Use `File.createTempFile(prefix, suffix)`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try:

```
String path = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
```

See: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties%28%29

And to add it here for completeness sake, as [wic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/53328/wic) mentioned in his comment, there's also the methods [`createTempFile(String prefix, String suffix)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) and [`createTempFile(String prefix, String suffix, File directory)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File)) methods from Java's [`File`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) class.

Comment: createTempFile() was what I exactly was looking, marked this as answer because of the completeness

Answer (score 3):

```
System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")
```

The [System](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties%28%29) and [Runtime](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) classes are those whose javadocs you should check first when something related to the system is required.

Answer (score 2):

In the spirit of 'let's solve the problem' instead of 'let's answer the specific question':

What type of input stream are you using when reading into Simple?  Be sure to use BufferedInputStream (or BufferedReader) - otherwise you are reading one byte/character at a time from the stream, which will be painfully slow when reading a network resource.

Instead of copying the file to local disk, buffer the inputs and you will be good to go.

Comment: In Simple you only specify what class needs to be the starting point of xml-serialization and a File object to where it needs to write the file. So the only thing I need to know is how to find the "temporary file directory", which others have answered for me.

Comment: You can also use streams if you like, for example in Simple you can use Serializer.write(myObject, new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("myFile.xml")))). This will buffer the output a little better for you if you like.

Comment: use a buffered stream - try it, I think you'll be surprised at the difference it makes.

Answer (score 1):

try  `System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");`